# How and where should I add a PATH?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, path

I need to add a new directory to my PATH so that SublimeText can find it. I assume this should be added to either .bash_profile, .bashrc, or .profile.

Which one should I add it to?

.bash_profile already has:

```
export PATH="/home/josh/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5/bin:/home/josh/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/mysql/bin:$PATH"
```

in it.

.bashrc and .profile both have:

export PATH="$PATH:$HOME/.rvm/bin"

in them.

Should I have all of these in just one of the files and do multiple 'export' statements just get chained together when processed, even if from different files?

Comment: From the other questions asnwer: `From the bash man page:

When bash is invoked as an interactive login shell, ... it first reads and executes commands from the file /etc/profile, if that file exists. After reading that file, it looks for ~/.bash_profile, ~/.bash_login, and ~/.profile, in that order, and reads and executes commands from the first one that exists and is readable.`
That seems to imply that only the first one that it can read will be read. Is that the case? If so, does that mean I should move all of the export PATH lines to .profile or they won't be read?

Answer (score -1):

if you look inside .bashrc file there is line like this:

```
# Put your fun stuff here.
```

... or something like that.

So, this is the place reserved for user declarations, export, alias, etc ... the practice is to put all your export PATH="..." there, in .bashrc file after mentioned comment or just at the end of file.

Comment: No. `.bashrc` is for interactive shell settings (completion, prompt, etc.). `.profile` (or `.bash_profile`, etc.) is for things done at login time such as environment variable definitions.

Comment: so .. the best place to define global variables are?

Comment: `.profile`, or `.pam_environment`. See the duplicate question for more details.